# Cannot Produce JSON with Maven quickstart grizzly Archetype

Tags: json, jersey, maven-archetype, grizzly

I've put some good hours trying to get my grizzly webserver to produce JSON.

Generated from maven archetype using Intellij, details:

```
groupId untitled3
artifactId  untitled3
version 1.0-SNAPSHOT
archetypeGroupId    org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes
archetypeArtifactId jersey-quickstart-grizzly2
archetypeVersion    2.0-m05
```

All online examples enable JSON using

```
rc.put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);
```

However, this does not work in jersey 2.x, put method does not exist.

In the application Main class, there is instructions on uncommenting a line of code to get JSON to work. When i uncomment this line of code, the method used does not exist.

```
public static HttpServer startServer() {
    // create a resource config that scans for JAX-RS resources and providers
    // in untitled2 package
    final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("untitled2");

    // uncomment the following line if you want to enable
    // support for JSON on the service (you also have to uncomment
    // dependency on jersey-media-json module in pom.xml)
    // --
    rc.addModule(org.glassfish.jersey.media.json.JsonJaxbModule);

    // create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
    // exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
    return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
}
```

When i try to serve a JSON response from a POJO object i get this error:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.example.JsonPost, genericType=class com.example.JsonPost.
```

I've no idea where to begin to look really. I've googled, plown through documentation and looked through user groups...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you uncomment the dependency in the POM. Then change the `addModule` call to this:

```java
rc.addModules(new org.glassfish.jersey.media.json.JsonJaxbModule());
```

and be sure to include the correct `@Produces` annotation on your resource:

```java
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

Comment: It's soooooo easy and obvious when you know how to do it. I'm serious, i could not find this information -anywhere-.